# Plotting a probability mass function for a poisson distribution

Tags: r, poisson

uppose that i have a poisson distribution with mean of 6 i would like to plot a probability mass function which includes an overlay of the approximating normal density.

This is what i have tried

```
 plot( dpois( x=0:10, lambda=6 ))
```

this produces

[image]

which is wrong since it doesnt contain an overlay of approxiamating noral density

How do i go about this?

Comment: Try `curve(dpois(x, lambda=6), xlim = c(0, 15), n = 16)` and for normal overlay `curve(dnorm(x, mean = 6, sd = sqrt(6)),add = TRUE, col = 'red')`

Comment: I would *not* evaluate the Poisson pmf where it's not defined nor join the points as a curve. So don't use `curve` on a Poisson. How does this issue arise (is this an exercise for a class)?

Comment: However, the suggestion of using `curve` for the normal is a good one; `add` is the argument that overlays them. An alternative would be to use `segments`

Answer (score 0):

Something like what you seem to be asking for (I'm outlining the commands and the basic ideas, but checking the help on the functions and trying should fill in the remaining details):

1. taking a wider range of x-values (out to at least 13 or so) and use `xlim` to extend the plot slightly into the negatives (maybe to `-1.5`) and
2. plotting the pmf of the Poisson with solid dots (similar to your command but with `pch=16` as an argument to plot) with a suitable color, then
3. call `points` with the same x and y arguments as above and have `type=h` and `lty=3` to get vertical dotted lines (to give a clear impression of the relative heights, somewhat akin to the appearance of a Cleveland dot-chart); I'd use the same colour as the dots or a slightly lighter/greyer version of the dot-colour
4. use `curve` to draw the normal curve with the same mean and standard deviation as the Poisson with mean 6 (see details at the Wikipedia page for the [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) which gives the mean and variance), but across the wider range we plotted; I'd use a slightly contrasting colour for that.
5. I'd draw a light x-axis in (e.g. using `abline` with the `h` argument)

Putting all those suggestions together:

[image: Poisson pmf with mean 6 and normal curve with the same mean and standard deviation]

(However, while it's what you're asking for it's not strictly a suitable way to compare discrete and continuous variables since density and  pmf are not on the same scale, since density is not probability -- the "right" comparison between a Poisson and an approximating normal would be on the scale of the cdfs so you compare like with like -- they'd both be on the scale of probabilities then)